# 2-time constant (On + decay) timer circuit

Tags: transistors, mosfet, analog, timer

Required is a timer circuit to switch on an LED with 2 time constants, when a switch is depressed as follows:

- when switch is closed, light an LED 10 ~ 20mA
- when switch is opened again, keep the LED on for approximately 5s more
- then fade LED  off for approximately 10s.
- circuit voltage = 3v
- assume a standard red LED , Vf =~ 1.8v
- prefer to have  maximize brightness
- small SMD low leakage caps <~22uF
- no ICs that consume continuous quiescent current; but accept minimum idle current (< 0.25uA @ 25'C)

<s>I'd like to use a mosfet to minimize voltage drop and maximize brightness.</s>

I think that it would involve some chain of transistors or mosfets that are held on by capacitors, but I can't figure out how to keep it on full brightness for the first 5s, as they would start to fade immediately as the voltage drains out of the capacitor.

[image]

Comment: What does "virtually no current" mean? I don't think we can design to that requirement.

Comment: Design Rule # 1. Never specify  component types unless absolutely necessary.  ONLY give all a) Input b) function and Output specs... plus other major restrictions.   Rule #2 when you specify the wrong parts read Rule #1 again. Ceramic has a leakage time constant less than 20 seconds. But that's OK. There's another way.  REWRITE your question using a datasheet point form approach with ALL SPECS including environment and tolerances for time and voltage, cost and mechanical construction. Now!  s'il vous plais!

Comment: If you outline in simple point form all parameters and tolerances  in next 1hr I will award 1 pt otherwise -1 pt. Others may agree.  Thankyou

Comment: How complex are you willing to go? Discrete, I see three NPN, one PNP, and one NFET which is in keeping with your capacitor limitations.

Comment: Are you not aware of the leakage time constants in capacitors especially ceramic?  Show me one capacitor with a time constant in the range you want. ( I know what to expect, but I want you to look)  again you specified ceramic when it is size, and function that is important.  Film caps are the only ones with long Δt=C*ΔV/I_leak

Answer (score 1):

It looks like I found a solution highly dependent on the device parameters.

[image]
Low leakage parts are the critical factor.
Take careful selection of Ids @ Vt and Vgs

Two inversions are done:   The 1st must have a gate threshold of << 1/3 to 1/2 of Vbat and not 2 to 4V. This is what causes decay on the 1st time constant.

- hi-side mechanical switch,
- low-side Nch   (inv)
- hi-side Pch    (inv)

**The critical factors in the selection of both FETS are:**

- the IDSS leakage current must be extremely low at Vgs near 0V.

  - Carefully select with Drain Resistor to result in a voltage drop less the next gate threshold.
- the threshold Vt or Vgs(th) @ Ids is critical because this acts as the voltage comparator for the 1st stage and the gradient declining LED intensity for the 2nd.
- Both have long time constants so capacitor leakage resistance at Vcap needs to be estimated for the ambient temp. Film caps are best but are low Dk large parts.